# Can't recursively normalize widget[name][]

Tags: php, recursion

Consider this simple form:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET)) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_GET, true), '</pre>';
}

?>

<form>

    <input type="text" name="widget[name][]" />
    <input type="text" name="widget[version][]" />


    <input type="text" name="widget[name][]" />
    <input type="text" name="widget[version][]" />

    <br />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

It gives the following output, when data is sent:

(I entered dummy values name1, name2 and version1, version2 respectively)

```
Array
(
    [widget] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => name1
                    [1] => name2
                )

            [version] => Array
                (
                    [0] => version1
                    [1] => version2
                )

        )

)
```

What I really want to do is to turn this into this:

```
Array
(
    [widget] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array(
                [name] => name1,
                [version] => version1
            ),

            [1] => Array(
                [name] => name2,
                [version] => version2
            )
        )
)
```

So, I've been trying to implement an algorithm which would be turning into this recursively, but I've failed many times. 
So I give up and need you guys to look at this from different angle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you change the HTML, it's the one that's not right?

```
<form>

    <input type="text" name="widget[0][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="widget[0][version]" />


    <input type="text" name="widget[1][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="widget[1][version]" />

    <br />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

If it's autogenerated from a PHP loop for instance, you could still manipulate the counter (0, 1...);

For the code conversion, as I already know what the pattern is:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET)) { 
    $widget = $_GET['widget'];
    $output = [];
    $i = 0;
    $keys = array_keys($widget);
    foreach ($widget as $value) {
        $output[$i] = [
            $keys[0] => $widget[$keys[0]][$i],
            $keys[1] => $widget[$keys[1]][$i]
        ];
        $i++;
    }

    echo '<pre>', print_r($output, true), '</pre>';
}

?>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1
            [version] => version1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2
            [version] => version2
        )

)
```

It will be a litter bit harder, but not impossible, if you have arbitrary number of keys (name, version, bla, blabla, etc...), then you could iterate through the keys, but in that example I presumed that if there are only 2 keys, that's not needed.

First we extract the keys, and put them as keys in each subarray. Then we populate them with the value of that key on that position from the original array E.g. with `widget[names][0]`

Comment: Yeah what you are suggesting is the first thing which came to mind, but no, I can't add indexes. I need a function which would turn what I have (without indexes) into the desired result

Comment: @bad_boy look at the edit of the answer, I added some code and explanation.